# How to process JSON string in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logic

I have a JSON string which needs to be process. I wanted to know whether there exists any predefined method or do I need to do it manually?

Intial String : {“organisation_name” : “GeeksforGeeks”, “description” : “A computer Science portal for Geeks”, “Employee” : “2000”}

Processed String : { \”organisation_name\” : \”GeeksforGeeks\”, \”description\” : \”A computer Science portal for Geeks\”, \”Employee\” : \”2000\” }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean about process?
if you want to use it as a class and check the fields you can use
ExClass exClass = objectMapper.readValue(json, ExClass .class);
to convert your JSON to a class then work with that class.

Comment: Ok @DaniyalVaghar, but my json is in the string format so don't I need to process it first? I was following this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-string-to-java-object-using-gson/

Comment: i dont think you need to process it but that code i gave you have a little problem,when you write a property in your json that not in the class mapper doesnt map that and that field dont show in your class.so your json properties and class properties should be exactly the same

Comment: yes  i used this lin   https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object